# Linux get all timestamp from log

Tags: regex, linux

Need help to get all the timestamp from a log using Linux  commends.
e.g.
if my log look like:

```
2014-10-26 15:30:51,121 bla bla bla
2014-10-26 15:30:51,122 bla bla bla
2014-10-26 15:30:51,123 bla bla bla
```

I need the list

```
15:30:51,121
15:30:51,122
15:30:51,123
```

Comment: simple `awk '{print $2}' file` or `cut -d' ' -f2 file` . Asked n number of times..

Answer (score 0):

You could grep it

```
 grep -E "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}" filename
```

I do like @AvinashRaj approach with `cut` though